# Hot depoyment in Jetty Application Server

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jboss, jetty

We are migrating from Jboss-as to Jetty. As of now as part of the continuous build and deployment process, Jenkins/Maven is being used to build and deploy the WAR to remote Jboss using the management native port(hot deployment). No physical WAR file is placed under the deployments folder. Below maven plugin is being used.

```
org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.6.Final:deploy-only -Djboss-as.hostname=server name -Djboss-as.port=server port
```

We cannot copy the WAR to webapps folder due to some restrictions. I am looking for a solution similar to jboss-as-maven-plugin, since Chef/Puppet/Ant Script/Shell Script, is not feasible for us.

Is there any similar process for hot deploying to remote jetty server without physically copying the WAR file?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Servlet which does this.

It only needs to accept a POST request, which contains some additional parameter headers required for the deplyoment (for example the file name), and the WAR in the request body.

Then upload the the WAR by POSTing it to the Servlet URL.

The Servlet would just write the binary data to the Jetty webapps directory.